# ignoring header content of a text

Tags: ruby

I want to get rid of the content of a file before "this word"
and only write the lines after that word on to disk.

```
text = <<EOT
  I only want
  the last lines
  of the file after
  this word. This is
  the content I 
  want. Yet this
  word can appear again.
EOT

puts text.scan("this word")
```

expected output:

```
This is
the content I 
want. Yet this
word can appear again.
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Any help appreciated

Ted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
irb(main):001:0> text = <<EOT
irb(main):002:0"   I only want
irb(main):003:0"   the last lines
irb(main):004:0"   of the file after
irb(main):005:0"   this word. This is
irb(main):006:0"   the content I 
irb(main):007:0"   want.
irb(main):008:0" EOT
=> "  I only want\n  the last lines\n  of the file after\n  this word. This is\n  the content I \n  want.\n"
irb(main):009:0> needle = 'this word. '
=> "this word. "
irb(main):012:0> text[text.index(needle)+needle.length..-1]
=> "This is\n  the content I \n  want.\n"
irb(main):013:0> print text[text.index(needle)+needle.length..-1]
This is
  the content I 
  want.
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'this word' appears only once in your test, or if you want to remove up to the last such phrase:

```
text.sub(/.*this word\W*/, '')
```

If there is possibility that 'this word' appears multiple time and you want to remove only up to the first of such:

```
text.sub(/.*?this word\W*/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use the partition method:

```
text.partition("this word. ").last
```

(this assumes that "this word. " actually appears in the variable text.  If it doesn't, an empty string will be returned by this code.)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work..  I get that partition expects a block.

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

method partition in test2.rb at line 13
at top level in test2.rb at line 13

Comment: It seems to be calling the partition in the Enumerable module for you instead of the one on String, but I don't really know why.  It is calling the one on String for me, which doesn't take a block.  Sorry -- I guess the other solutions are better for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
text.split('this word. ')[1]
```

Or

```
text.split('this word. ').last
```

Comment: I thought of that one but the problem is that actually this word may appear in the file more than once, I only care for the first instance